# Appearing order in a landscape figure and normal figure

Tags: floats, positioning, landscape, afterpage, pdflscape

I'm working in a text with a lot of figures and some of them are landscape oriented. In the text I created a landscape figure, followed by some paragraphs and then a regular figure. I expected that the landscape oriented figure appears first, and then the regular figure, however it is not happening. How can I place the landscape figure first than the other one? I have aready tested the afterpage command

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\afterpage{%
\begin{landscape}%<--- Created first
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=12cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example image a}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
}
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\begin{figure}[htb]%<--- Created second
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Example image b}
\end{figure}
\blindtext\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

I used the @JohnKormylo's suggestion and it worked. However, the figure numbers are not in the correct order. How can I solve it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\makeatletter%<---@JohnKormylo's suggestion
\newcommand{\savefloats}{%
  \global\let\old@toplist=\@toplist
  \global\let\old@midlist=\@midlist
  \global\let\old@botlist=\@botlist
  \global\let\old@deferlist=\@deferlist
  \global\let\old@dbltoplist=\@dbldtoplist
  \global\let\old@dbldeferlist=\@dbldeferlist
  \global\let\@toplist=\@empty
  \global\let\@midlist=\@empty
  \global\let\@botlist=\@empty
  \global\let\@deferlist=\@empty
  \global\let\@dbltoplist=\@empty
  \global\let\@dbldeferlist=\@empty
  \xdef\old@colroom{\the\@colroom}
  \xdef\old@toproom{\the\@toproom}
  \xdef\old@botroom{\the\@botroom}
  \xdef\old@topnum{\the\@topnum}
  \xdef\old@botnum{\the\@botnum}
}
\newcommand{\restorefloats}{%
  \global\let\@toplist=\old@toplist
  \global\let\@midlist=\old@midlist
  \global\let\@botlist=\old@botlist
  \global\let\@deferlist=\old@deferlist
  \global\let\@dbltoplist=\old@dbltoplist
  \global\let\@dbldeferlist=\old@dbldeferlilst
  \global\@colroom=\old@colroom\relax
  \global\@toproom=\old@toproom\relax
  \global\@botroom=\old@botroom\relax
  \global\@topnum=\old@topnum\relax
  \global\@botnum=\old@botnum\relax
  \global\vsize=\@colroom
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\afterpage{\savefloats%<--- Solution
\begin{landscape}%<--- Created first
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=12cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example image a (must be Figure 1)}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\restorefloats}%<--- Solution
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\begin{figure}[htb]%<--- Created second
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Example image b (must be Figure 2)}
\end{figure}
\blindtext\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you throw in one more \blindtext, or anything to force the portrait figure to not be created until AFTER the landcape page, it will go second.  \begin{landscape} performs \clearpage which will print any floats in the queue immediately.

Comment: latex always keeps figures in the order they are entered, but you have used `\afterpage` to change the order.  Perhaps you are looking for `sidewaysfigure`  from the `rotating` package?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `sidewasyfigure` is perfect for what I need. However I've been tryed with `landscape` environment because the pdf rotated page. It is a dilemma, float the figure or pretty pdf page orientation

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295270/how-to-get-rotated-landscape-page-in-latex-without-flushing-other-floats/295526?s=2|30.8041#295526

Comment: @JohnKormylo It worked!!!

Comment: @JohnKormylo Sorry, but I was excited. It worked, however the figures numbering is wrong. The first figure appears first but numbered as Figure 2

Comment: I revised my solution here to handle the caption and the float queue.

Answer (score 2):

Floats are always kept in order that they are executed, but `\afterpage` just stores its content as tokens so the landscape figure is seen after the normal one if you do it that way. (`\afterpage` is very fragile you should only use it as a last resort)

You can use `sidewaysfigure` to have rotaated figures that float as normal.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par

\begin{sidewaysfigure}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=12cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Example image a}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\begin{figure}[htbp]%<--- Created second (don't forget p :-)
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Example image b}
\end{figure}
\blindtext\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: `sidewaysfigure` is perfect, so how can I rotate the pdf page like `landscape` does?

Comment: @DanielValenciaC. well you can't really (or at least sideways figure doesn't)  as lscape knows it is dealing with landcape pages but sideways figure just rotates the figure. Your example is large so it takes the whole page but in general you might have a small sideways figure appearing (rotated) at the top of a normal portrait page. sidewaysfigure just rotates the _contents_ of the float it does not know where the float will be positioned (and the latex float algorithm doesn't know the contents are rotated)

Comment: One can rotate single pages with the pdflscape package:  `\makeatletter\PLS@Rotate{0}abc\newpage \PLS@Rotate{90} abc\newpage \PLS@Rotate{0} abc` works fine. With floats the main problem is how to do it on the correct page and how to stop it (it can not be grouped).

Answer (score 1):

I combined the `\savefloats` and `\restorefloats` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295270/how-to-get-rotated-landscape-page-in-latex-without-flushing-other-floats/295526?s=2%7C30.8041#295526) with the `\savebox` from earlier.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[%
    left=3.00cm,
    right=2.00cm,
    top=3.00cm,
    bottom=2.00cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\setcaptype}[1]{\def\@captype{#1}}

\newcommand{\savefloats}{% this is probably overkill, but better safe than sorry
  \global\let\old@toplist=\@toplist
  \global\let\old@midlist=\@midlist
  \global\let\old@botlist=\@botlist
  \global\let\old@deferlist=\@deferlist
  \global\let\old@dbltoplist=\@dbldtoplist
  \global\let\old@dbldeferlist=\@dbldeferlist
  \global\let\@toplist=\@empty
  \global\let\@midlist=\@empty
  \global\let\@botlist=\@empty
  \global\let\@deferlist=\@empty
  \global\let\@dbltoplist=\@empty
  \global\let\@dbldeferlist=\@empty
  \xdef\old@colroom{\the\@colroom}% store as macros
  \xdef\old@toproom{\the\@toproom}% store as macros
  \xdef\old@botroom{\the\@botroom}% store as macros
  \xdef\old@topnum{\the\@topnum}% store as macros
  \xdef\old@botnum{\the\@botnum}% store as macros
}
\newcommand{\restorefloats}{%
  \global\let\@toplist=\old@toplist
  \global\let\@midlist=\old@midlist
  \global\let\@botlist=\old@botlist
  \global\let\@deferlist=\old@deferlist
  \global\let\@dbltoplist=\old@dbltoplist
  \global\let\@dbldeferlist=\old@dbldeferlilst
  \global\@colroom=\old@colroom\relax
  \global\@toproom=\old@toproom\relax
  \global\@botroom=\old@botroom\relax
  \global\@topnum=\old@topnum\relax
  \global\@botnum=\old@botnum\relax
  \global\vsize=\@colroom
}
\makeatother

\newsavebox{\lsfigure}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\savebox{\lsfigure}{% increment figure/caption counter
  \begin{minipage}{\textheight}
  \setcaptype{figure}\centering
  \includegraphics[height=12cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Example image a}
  \end{minipage}}%
\afterpage{\savefloats
  \begin{landscape}%<--- Created first
  \begin{figure}
  \usebox{\lsfigure}
  \end{figure}
  \end{landscape}
  \restorefloats}%
\blindtext\par
\blindtext\par
\begin{figure}[htb]%<--- Created second
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Example image b}
\end{figure}
\blindtext\par
\end{document}
```