# How to rotate a page with a rotated figure with "sidewaysfigure"?

Tags: rotating, landscape, afterpage, sidewaysfigure

I'm dealing with rotated figures on my document. I have 2 alternatives:

1. `sidewaysfigure`from the `rotating` package
2. `landscape` environment from the `pdflscape` package

I prefer the `sidewaysfigure` because the figure floats better, however, I'd like to get the PDF as what `landscape` makes. I don't like to use `landscape` because I have to add `\afterpage{...}` to avoid undesirable white space in the document before the rotated page and sometimes, is not compatible with other packages.

Is there a way, using `slidewaysfigure`, to rotate the PDF the page with the figure?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphics, graphicx}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\par%
%
\begin{sidewaysfigure}%<-- Perfect placement of the figure and text before and after
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure a}
\label{Fig:a}
\end{sidewaysfigure}%
%
\Blindtext\par%
%
\begin{landscape}%<-- makes undesirable withe space before the rotated page
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Figure b}
\label{Fig:b}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}%
%
\Blindtext\par%
%
\afterpage{%<-- undesirable use
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{Figure c}
\label{Fig:c}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}%
}%
%
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked for me: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/471472/how-to-make-figures-appear-landscape-properly

Comment: You can also use \afterpage (afterpage package) with pdflscape.  Best example I could find was https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295270/how-to-get-rotated-landscape-page-in-latex-without-flushing-other-floats?r=SearchResults&s=2|42.6875