# How to organize the appearing of floats when afterpage is used?

Tags: floats, rotating, afterpage

earlier I asked how to rotate a page with a `sidewaysfigure` inside ([question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/475340/107689)). However I couldn't find a solution. I decided to use the `landscape` environment with `afterpage`, but when there's other floats near to the rotated one, the appearing order is altered.

In the following MWE, I expected to get the first page full of text, then the rotated figure, and finally the text and floats remaining.

How can I solve it?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphics, graphicx}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\par%
%
\afterpage{%
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure a}
\label{Fig:a}
\end{figure}%
\end{landscape}
\clearpage%
}%
%
\blindtext\par%
%
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Figure b}
\label{Fig:b}
\end{figure}
%
\Blindtext\par%
%
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{Figure c}
\label{Fig:c}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: figure b is only allowed to come `[h]ere` as you used the optional arguemt to prevent all other options so that forces it to appear in the text, and figure a you forced to come after that by using `\afterpage`  so I can't see what other order you would expect?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I expected that the figure a comes first, because it was called first, and before the figures b and c there is a little of text explaining the figure content, then I think that is not correct to put all the floats inside the `afterpage`

Comment: as I explained before the content of `\afterpage` is just an internal definition it is not interpreted _at all_ so the first figure that tex sees is B, then A is only seen after the afterpage tokens are inserted at the start of the next page.

Comment: the whole point of floats is that they _move_  that is why they have captions, so any text in the main document flow should refer indirectly to the figure via its label, not be written assuming that it appears in any particular place. I wouldn't use afterpage, but if you use it for one, and you want some other figures to be in the  same sequence, you must use it for all.

Answer (score 2):

You were explictly forcing A to come after B, if I understand you correctly you want something more like

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{graphics, graphicx}

\begin{document}

\blindtext\par%
%
\afterpage{%
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Figure a}
\label{Fig:a}
\end{figure}%
\end{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Figure b}
\label{Fig:b}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\caption{Figure c}
\label{Fig:c}
\end{figure}
}%
%
\blindtext\par%
%

%
\Blindtext\par%
%
\end{document}
```