# What do floats mean?

Tags: floats

I'm reading an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45619/223253), which says something about "floats" in latex, bold displayed below. What does that mean?

> First of all, as you already mentioned \clearpagenot only ends the page (or column in two column mode) but additionally it flushes out all floats that have been deferred. On the face of it that might be a good idea but consider the following situation: **you have one float waiting** which is just 1/3 of the page size. Now with \newpage you start a new page and then the float algorithm (see description of this algorithm for details) would kick in and try to place waiting floats onto the next page (and most likely would assign the waiting float to the top area of the next page. In contrast \clearpagewould also output this float but on a page of its own.

Comment: Floats in LaTeX are the elements like figures and tables that are supposed to be placed in an appropriate place by the compiler. They are usually placed on top of next page or no bottom of next page and only if they can fit (but also if LaTeX thinks that placing them there is good typography) will be placed in the specific place that the are in the code. Hope that helped.

Comment: For an in-depth discussion of how LaTeX places floats, see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5001)

Comment: You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295270/how-to-get-rotated-landscape-page-in-latex-without-flushing-other-floats amusing.