# Paracol and floats placement

Tags: floats, paracol

If I use a float in the same page where I have the paracol environment, the floats get placed where it is irrespective from the argument. See my MWE. The float on page 1 should be at the bottom, like the one in page 2, but it stays at the top. Why? (If I comment out the paracol all goes well)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[]{lipsum}
\usepackage{paracol}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[b]
   Some text that should go at the bottom.
\end{figure}


\columnratio{0.65}
  \begin{paracol}{2}
  \sloppy
  \noindent
  Some text in two columns.
  \switchcolumn
 
  \noindent
  {\scriptsize Some more text in the second column.} \end{paracol}

\lipsum{1}
\begin{figure}[b]
    Some text that should go at the bottom.
 \end{figure}
 \lipsum{1}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Paracol apparently terminates the existing page (\box255} when it starts, so the first figure goes above the top of paracol.  The second figure doesn't get created until you are alreacy on the second page.  (see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295270/how-to-get-rotated-landscape-page-in-latex-without-flushing-other-floats)

Comment: It works BUT only if I have little text in paracol columns. Try to insert \lipsum{1} in each columns and you will see that the float goes at the bottom of page 3 AFTER the end of the paracol environment. Also, when I tried the code in my real text (book in octavo document class), I had cases in which the float was down in the footer space and overlapping the page number.

Comment: And sorry I have not enough knowledge to play with your macros... I just copied and pasted.

Comment: Other functions which change the column width, like `\twocolumn`, `\newgeometry` or `landscape`, cause a `\clearpage` to empty the queue first.  Why should `paracol` be any different?  BTW, I forgot that there can only be one bottom float per page (`bottomnumber` =1).

Comment: I'm not complaining! Paracol is a very good package and every day I find a new use. Just wanting to know if there is a way to have bottom floats over several pages of paracol columns, but I guess the answer is not. But thanks for trying John!

Comment: BTW, `\lipsum[1]` does one paragraph, while `\lipsum{1}` is the same as `\lipsum{}1`.

Comment: Understood thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your footnote idea and bypsssed `\footnote` to write directly into `\footins`.  The tricky bit was turning off `\footnoterule`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\newsavebox{\Bfloat}
\let\OldFootnoterule=\footnoterule
\newlength{\OldFootnotesep}
\setlength{\OldFootnotesep}{\footnotesep}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{Bfigure}{\begin{lrbox}{\Bfloat}%
  \minipage{\textwidth}%
  \def\@captype{figure}}%
{\endminipage%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \insert\footins{\noindent\usebox\Bfloat}%
  \global\let\footnoterule\relax% will need global reset
  \global\footnotesep=\textfloatsep}
\makeatother
  
\footnotelayout{m}

\begin{document}

\columnratio{0.55}
\begin{paracol}{2}

    \sloppy
\begin{Bfigure}
  \caption{A bottom float. \lipsum[1]}
\end{Bfigure}  
  \lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn\sloppy
  {\footnotesize \lipsum[1]}
\end{paracol}
\afterpage{\global\let\footnoterule\OldFootnoterule
  \global\footnotesep=\OldFootnotesep}%

\lipsum[1]

Test\footnote{a normal footnote}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is ingenious and it solves my issue. Thanks John!

Comment: BTW, \count\footins and \dimen\footins are also supposed to contain information, but I forgot to set them.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get the layout I want using, instead of figure floats, footnotes without marker. Please see this post that thought me how to get rid of the markers: [Footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker). Maybe it is not a very elegant solution but does anyone see an alternative?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}
\renewcommand*\footnoterule{}
%\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
\footnotelayout{m}
\begin{document}


\columnratio{0.55}
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \sloppy
 \blfootnote{ {\scriptsize \hspace{-16pt} A bottom float. \lipsum{1}}}\lipsum[1]
\switchcolumn\sloppy
  {\footnotesize \lipsum[1]}
\end{paracol}
\blfootnote{ {\scriptsize \hspace{-16pt} This is a second bottom float. This is a second bottom float. This is a second bottom float. This is a second bottom float. This is a second bottom float. This is a second bottom float. This is a second bottom float. This is a second bottom float. This is a second bottom float. This is a second bottom float. This is a second bottom float. }}

\end{document}
```